# Sorted maps in groovy

Tags: java, groovy, dictionary

I am interested in using a sorted map in groovy (with gremlin which is a DSL for graph databases).

I have looked at this [blog post](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/groovy-goodness-sorting-map.html) on sorted maps here, but I am still a bit confused.

- How are sorted maps declared? Is it any different from the standard way for maps `y = [:]`?
- When using a sorted map, are items inserted into the list going to be in the order they are inserted? Or will I have to run `sort{}` before the items in the sorted map are sorted?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you just declare a map like so:

```
def m = [:]
```

Then, you can see Groovy by default makes a `LinkedHashMap`

```
assert m.getClass().name == 'java.util.LinkedHashMap'
```

If you look at the [documentation for LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) it says:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order).

So `LinkedHashMap` has an order, and you can affect that order in Groovy by calling `sort`

```
def m = [ b:1, a:2 ]

// Sort by descending value
m = m.sort { -it.value }

println m // prints [a:2, b:1]
```

If you want natural ordering of the keys, then you can use one of Java's sorted maps, such as `TreeMap`

To Say you want to use this in Groovy, you can do:

```
// def tm = [ tim_yates:1, F21:2 ] as TreeMap // works as well
TreeMap tm = [ tim_yates:1, F21:2 ]
```

Then printing this, you can see it is ordered by the keys:

```
println map // prints [F21:b, tim_yates:a]
```

A `TreeMap` will maintain order as you add keys.  A `LinkedHashMap` will not automatically remain sorted when you add new values.