# Groovy expand tuple/map to arguments

Tags: groovy, arguments, parameter-passing

Is it possible to expand a map to a list of method arguments

In Python it is possible, eg.
[Expanding tuples into arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993727/expanding-tuples-into-arguments)

I have a `def map = ['a':1, 'b':2]`
and a method `def m(a,b)`

I want to write smt like `m(*map)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [spread operator](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.es/2009/09/groovy-goodness-spread-operator.html) (*) is used to tear a list apart into single elements. This can be used to invoke a method with multiple parameters and then spread a list into the values for the parameters.

List (lists in Groovy are closest related with tuples in Python<sup>[1](http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Why-has-groovy-no-built-in-tuple-support-like-map-and-lists-td360532.html),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/626759/whats-the-difference-between-list-and-tuples-in-python)</sup>):

```
list = [1, 2]
m(*list)
```

Map:

```
map = [a: 1, b: 2]
paramsList = map.values().toList()
m(*paramsList)
```

An importan point is that you pass the arguments by position.

Comment: *you pass the arguments by position*.. what is the order of the elements in a map?

Comment: A map is a mapping from unique unordered keys to values, but you can emulate order by clause with sort(), see the [Map documentation](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN1035-Maps)

Comment: I understand how maps work, but some are ordered, some not, some are sorted, some not. For instance: if I have a method `def m(a,b)` and a map `def map = [b:1, a:2]` then what will be the method call - `m(1,2)` or `m(2,1)` or undefined......

Comment: I'm not sure. I think that if you have a map `def map = [b:1, a:2]` the method call is `m(1,2)` but the implementation could change in the future, it's depend on the data structures used under the hood. Groovy documentation says that a map is an unordered keys to values. You can learn more about this topic here: [Sorted maps in groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13410551/462015)

Comment: OK. So basically, what I need is currently unavailable in groovy, meaning that your solution is a bit hacky... (?)

Comment: Is the same case as [dictionaries in Python](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries): _dictionary returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just use sorted(d.keys()) instead)_

Comment: Groovy looks soo much like python I almost thought this was the wrong answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best I can currently think of is:

```
@groovy.transform.Canonical
class X {
  def a
  def b

  def fn( a, b ) {
    println "Called with $a $b"
  }
}

def map = [ a:1, b:2 ]

def x = new X( map.values().toList() )

x.fn( map.values().toList() )
```

However, that takes the order of the map, and not the names of the keys into consideration when calling the function/constructor.

You probably want to add a function/constructor that takes a Map, and do it that way

Comment: `*map` uses the spread operator? I've seen it used only on methods like `map*.values()` How to understand the above code?

Comment: it gets the `values()` from the map, converts them `toList()`, and then spreads that list.  Adding a brace might help you see what's going on:  `new X( *(map.values().toList()) )`

Comment: I don't understand the use of `*map`. You can simply write `map.values().toList()` and works fine!

Comment: @ArturoHerrero Haha, oh yeah...  The `*` was superfluous :-/

Comment: Spread operator doesn't work in this case: `def f(Map opts) { println("${opts}") }; f(*[a: 1, b: 2])`. The equivalent Python code works fine (you need to insert a newline instead of `;`): `def f(**kwargs): print(str(kwargs)); f(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})`

Comment: @haridsv the map spread operator is `*:` in groovy `f(*:[a: 1, b: 2])`

Comment: Thank you @tim_yates, that works! I actually meant to leave my comment on the accepted answer, so it looks out of context here and yet you still responded so I appreciate you for that.

Answer (score -3):

```
   mmap = { 'a':1, 'b':2 }

   def m( a, b ):
       return a+b
   print m( **mmap )
```

30

3

Comment: This is how it's done in Python, but the `**` operator doesn't exist in Groovy