# Replace strings in an existing string in Groovy

Tags: java, regex, groovy

How would you best "truncate" the following variable in Groovy/Java?

```
def p = '{"name" : "%token%", "lastName" : "%c%e", "addrMngr" : "%xyz", "postCode" : "%x"}'
```

In other words, how can I generically get from:

```
def p = '{"name" : "%token%", "lastName" : "%c%e", "addrMngr" : "%xyz", "postCode" : "%x"}'
```

to

```
def p = '{"name" : "", "lastName" : "", "addrMngr" : "", "postCode" : ""}'
```

Ignore the usage of `%` in the "values" list above, and in the future this String may grow bigger with more data.

Answer (score 2):

I think what OP has is string which is actually a `json`.

Here is what you can do it with `JsonSlurper` and convert it back to string.

```
def p = '{"name" : "%token%", "lastName" : "%c%e", "addrMngr" : "%xyz", "postCode" : "%x"}'
def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(p)
json.keySet().collect{json."$it" = ''}
def result = groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(json)
println "Resultant after transformation: $result"
assert result instanceof String
```

Answer (score 1):

The original `p` is very close to being map syntax in Groovy; with a slight change, we can evaluate it into a true map (a [LinkedHashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13413729/12704), no less, re: key order).

Assuming performance is not vital, consider the following (no regexes):

```
def p = '{"name" : "%token%", "lastName" : "%c%e", "addrMngr" : "%xyz", "postCode" : "%x"}'

def m = p.replace('{','[').replace('}',']')
def map = evaluate(m)

def buffer = new StringBuilder()
buffer.append("{")

map.eachWithIndex { key, val, index ->
    buffer.append(/"${key}" : ""/)
    if (index < map.keySet().size() - 1) {
        buffer.append(', ')
    }
} 

buffer.append("}")

def p2 = '{"name" : "", "lastName" : "", "addrMngr" : "", "postCode" : ""}'

assert p2 == buffer.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try it with regex:

```
p.replaceAll("\" : \".*\", \"", "\" : \"\", \"");
```

That's a start.
Finetuning the regex is possible, too, e.g. make the spaces optional.